# using gZipStream with one or two memory streams makes a big difference

Tags: c#, compression, memorystream, gzipstream, binaryformatter

I am definitely missing something very obvious but can anyone explain why there is a lot better compression rate in second case?!

Case 1: very low compression and sometimes even growth in size.

```
using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
{
  new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(gZipStream, obj);
  gZipStream.Close();
  return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Case 2: a lot better compression and I did not get a size growth.

```
using (MemoryStream msCompressed = new MemoryStream())
using (GZipStream gZipStream = new GZipStream(msCompressed, CompressionMode.Compress))
using (MemoryStream msDecompressed = new MemoryStream())
{
  new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(msDecompressed, obj);
  byte[] byteArray = msDecompressed.ToArray();

  gZipStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
  gZipStream.Close();
  return msCompressed.ToArray();
}
```

I have done mirrored decompression and in both cases I can deserialize it into source object without any issues.

Here are some stats:

> UncSize: 58062085B,     Comp1: 46828139B,       0.81%
>
> UncSize: 58062085B,     Comp2: 31326029B,       0.54%
>
> UncSize: 7624735B,      Comp1: 7743947B,        1.02%
>
> UncSize: 7624735B,      Comp2: 5337522B,        0.70%
>
> UncSize: 1237628B,      Comp1: 1265406B,        1.02%
>
> UncSize: 1237628B,      Comp2: 921695B,         0.74%

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't say which version of .NET you're using. In versions prior to 4.0, `GZipStream` compresses data on a per-write basis. That is, it compresses the buffer you send to it. In your first example, the `Serialize` method is likely writing very small buffers to the stream (one field at a time). In your second example, `Serialize` serializes the entire object to the memory stream, and then the memory stream's buffer is written to the `GZipStream` in one big chunk. `GZipStream` does much better when it has a larger buffer (64K is close to optimum) to work with.

This may still be the case in .NET 4.0. I don't remember if I tested it.

The way I've handled this in the past is with a [BufferedStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx):

```
using (var mstream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var bstream = new BufferedStream(new GZipStream(mstream, CompressionMode.Compress), 65536))
    {
        new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(btream, obj);
    }
    return mstream.ToArray();
}
```

That way, the compressor gets a 64K buffer to work with.

Prior to .NET 4.0, there was no benefit to providing a buffer larger than 64K for `GZipStream`. I've seen some information indicating that the compressor in .NET 4.0 can do a better job of compression with a larger buffer. However, I've not tested that myself.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.
I am using .net 4.0 and this is still the case there. As you said 64k works the best. Smaller buffers cause weaker compression.
I have changed my code to use BufferStream instead of two memory streams to have better memory management. Thanks